# UILongPressGestureRecognizer- How increase size while holding down

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uikit, gesture-recognition

I am trying to make a feature where while the user is holding their finger down, an image grows until it is a certain size when a transition occurs. I know how to make the image grow, but do not know how to make it grow ONLY WHEN the user is holding down.

Does anyone know how to make this occur? Does one need the LongPressRecognizer?

Sorry for no code, but I am just trying to figure out how to do this. Thanks so much for your help in advance!

Cheers,
Theo

Comment: Yes, you can use LongPressRecognizer for this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!

var startAnimation = false
func handleTap(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) {

        startAnimation = true
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.myImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }) { (finished) in
            self.startAnimation = false
        }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let gesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(gestureRecognizer:)))

    myImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    myImageView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! This looks perfect for an iOS app, but I am trying to do this programmatically on a playground. I can convert the viewdidload and stuff like that, but how would you go about creating the image a button and then have it execute the code? If this is too much to ask, just tell me and I will search for it myself. I'll give you the check mark no problem

Comment: I implemented the code into my playground and it works... sort of. The long press expands it, but if I let go, it doesn't shrink back. That is what I was asking for. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: I really don't understand why u use playground. However.. Please use google for your question. The question isn't rare. gestureRecognizer  has a state: gestureRecognizer.state maybe that will help you.